How to change state of child function component in yew?
I am writing a web application in rust with yew framework.
I have a function_component ImageViewer, which allows one to view, move and zoom an image.
It has offset and zoom use_state hooks inside.
Also I have a function_component App, that contains ImageViewer and button to reset its state.
So the code looks like this:
#[autoprops]
#[function_component]
pub fn ImageViewer(src: &String) -> Html {
    let zoom = use_state(|| 1.);
    let offset = use_state(|| (0., 0.));

    let onwheel = {
        let zoom = zoom.clone();
        Callback::from(move |e: WheelEvent| { /* update zoom */ })
    };

    let onmousemove = {
        let offset = offset.clone();
        Callback::from(move |e: MouseEvent| { /* update offset */ })
    };

    let image_style = use_style!(
        r#"
            transform: translate(${offset_x}px, ${offset_y}px) scale(${zoom});
            user-select: none;
        "#,
        zoom=*zoom,
        offset_x=(*offset).0,
        offset_y=(*offset).1,
    );

    html! {
        <div {onwheel} {onmousemove}>
            <img {src} class={image_style}/>
        </div>
    }
}

#[function_component]
pub fn App() -> Html {
    let onclick = Callback::from(|_| {
        // TODO: set ImageViewer.zoom to 1.
        // TODO: set ImageViewer.offset to (0., 0.)
    });

    html! {
        <div>
            <ImageViewer/>
            <button {onclick}>{"Reset image"}</button>
        </div>
    }
}

What is the best way to change zoom and offset of ImageViewer from App? Is it possible to somehow access ImageViewer's zoom and offset from App or maybe call some ImageViewer's function from App?ImageViewer

The best solution, I came up with, is to move
let zoom = use_state(|| 1.);
let offset = use_state(|| (0., 0.));

from ImageViewer to App and change them with on_zoom_changed and on_offset_changed callbacks.
But I don't like this solution because zoom and offset idiomatically seem to be a part of ImageViewer's state, rather than App's.

With Yew the direction of callbacks is such that inner components can use callbacks to affect outer components. Thus if you want your zoom reset control to live in the App, then the zoom state should also live there. Alternatively move the control down into the Viewer.
